# CakePHP Link Help

Tags: php, cakephp

How can I get this to output the span tags correctly: `echo $this->Html->link('<span>Log in</span>', '/', array('title' => 'Log in', 'id' => 'login'));`

I've tried using `&gt;` `&lt;` instead of the < and > but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1442/link

> HTML special characters in `$title` will be converted to HTML entities. To disable this conversion, set the `escape` option to `false` in the `$options` array.

http://api.cakephp.org/class/html-helper#method-HtmlHelperlink

> **Options**
>
> `escape` Set to `false` to disable escaping of title and attributes.

```
echo $this->Html->link('<span>Log in</span>', '/',
          array('title' => 'Log in', 'id' => 'login', 'escape' => false));
```